# Error updating Ruby gem sequel_pg

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sequel-gem

when I try to install the Ruby gem sequel_pg I get the following error meassage:

```
~$ sudo gem update
Updating installed gems
Updating sequel_pg
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sequel_pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpq... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... no
creating Makefile

make
compiling sequel_pg.c
sequel_pg.c: In function ‘spg_timestamp_error’:
sequel_pg.c:279:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-                Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [sequel_pg.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel_pg-1.6.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel_pg-1.6.5/ext/sequel_pg/gem_make.out
Nothing to update
```

I am running Lubuntu 13.04. The depencies: pg and sequel are installed. Packages files postgresql and postgresql-server-dev-9.1 is also installed

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in [master](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel_pg) of the gem [with this patch](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel_pg/commit/cd097a6db973c819fa984470a4cd3c4d4044ccf5). You should wait for new release or install head version of the gem.